# what is the difference between this 2 protocol's method

Tags: objective-c, methods, protocols, nstableview

Can someone tell me the difference between this 2 method
for this method below the apple's developers does not have any explanation

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn               *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

and this

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:   (NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
```

Sets the data object for an item in the specified row and column.

Answer (score 3):

First one is used to show the value. This is a **required method**, if binding is not used.

Second one to update/edit/enter. This is an optional method.

Comment: you answer is different from the answer given above by trojanfoe

Comment: No we both mean same thing.  I Only added required and optional thing.

Answer (score 2):

The first one *gets* the object value and the second *sets* the value for a table column.

Comment: Thanks just realized that